# Jest Testing: How to import react components when the whole react app is in a typescript module

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library, ts-jest

I'm having my whole project in a module and now I want to cover this project with tests but I can't figure out how to import props so, I can access desired components that I want to test or import 'render from testing-library/react'.
My component looks like this:

**MyComponent.tsx**

```js
module MainModule {

    interface Props extends ReactTabComponentProps {
    }

    interface State extends ReactComponentState {
    }

    export class MyComponent extends ReactTabComponent<Props, State> {
        constructor(props: Props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
            };
        }

        setTitle = () => {
            this.props.tab.setTitle(
                <span>
                    <Icon name="calculator" fixedWidth />
                    MainComponent
                </span>
            );
        }

        render() {
            return (
                
            );
        }
    }
}
```

And I can't figure out how to access above component in my test. My test looks like this:

**MyComponent.test.tsx**

```js
module MainModule {

 import { MainComponent } from '../Main/components/MainComponent';
 import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
 
    describe("mainComponentTest", () => {
        it("should renders correctly", async () => { 
           
        });


    });
}
```

With this, I get TS errors, Error:*Import declarations in a namespace cannot reference a module.*

And if I remove module from my test or write imports outside of module then I get the error:

```
(TS)Cannot compile modules using option 'outFile' unless the '--module'flag is 'amd' or 'system'.
```

and I don't want to remove outFile option from my ts.config file

Comment: Don't use `module {}` anymore. Use a bundler like parcel to concatenate files together into a single file.

Comment: @DanPantry I'm using C# bundling (ScriptBundle)